# Adding elements to jQuery search results

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, clone

I'm creating an app which has a jQuery search function to search the app. The search correctly identifies and outputs the result of the search. What I'd like to do now is output the search result followed by the next div element in the app. The next div contains a variable number of other divs.

The original search statement which works is:

```
var $searchResults = $(".english:contains(" + $searchTerm + ")").html();
```

and here's what I thought would add the next div and it's descendants

```
var $searchResults = $(".english:contains(" + $searchTerm + ")").html().next().clone();
```

Unfortunately the console log shows an error

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'next'

I've set up a test page here  http://lawenforcementspanish.com/testsearch.php

Thanks for any assistance you can provide - I'm new to this jQuery stuff.

Comment: `.html()` returns a string. `.next()` is a function on jQuery objects

Comment: I think you could use .append() to do what you're after http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @blgt - thanks for the suggestion, I'm new at this and thought I was chaining the .next and .clone

Comment: @mastazi - thanks I tried append but got the same results as .next .clone